# Powershell | Delete Folder and is content, inside a Zip archive

Tags: powershell, zip

I searched the net for a while and I almost thought I had the solution, but no

I need to update things in a Zip file without recompressing the whole Zip file each time.
I know how to update my Zip without problem, I can add things, but not remove them. Specifically, I can delete a file, but not a folder with files
I thought that updating a folder in the Zip would overwrite all of its contents, deleting what is not there any more but no, that only adds what is new.

Here is the function I wrote :

```
function RetraitElemZip
{
    param ([string]$Zip, [string]$Cible)

    if (Test-Path -Path $Zip -PathType Leaf)
    {
        $LecteurZip = [io.compression.zipfile]::Open($Zip,'Update')
        $Recherche = $LecteurZip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.fullname -match $Cible}

        if ($Recherche.Count -lt 1)
        { Write-Host("Impossible de retirer l'élément < $Cible > de < $Zip > !!") }
        else
        {
            foreach ($e in $Recherche)
            { $e.Delete() }
        }

        $LecteurZip.Dispose()
    }
    else
    { Write-Host("Le Fichier Zip < $Zip > n'est pas valide !!") }
}
```

But the search seems to not find any matching entries and I have run tests with valid addresses without success.

My questions are therefore the following :
Where is the error in my code?
How to delete a folder and all its contents, inside a Zip file?
Or, how to update a folder in a Zip file to remove items that are no longer there.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close to the answer and eventually found it ... I just needed to study regex in more detail.
The problem was with the "\" in the paths because they serve as an escape character (I thought it was "` ") so I had to duplicate them.

Here is my corrected function:

```
function RetraitElemZip
{
    param ([string]$Zip, [string]$Cible)

    if (Test-Path -Path $Zip -PathType Leaf)
    {
        # doubler les "\" dans le chemin car ce sont des caractères d'échapements
        $Temp = $Cible.Split("\")
        $Cible = $Temp[0]
        for ($i = 1; $i -lt $Temp.Count; ++$i)
        { $Cible += "\\{0}" -f $Temp[$i] }

        $LecteurZip = [io.compression.zipfile]::Open($Zip,'Update')
        $Recherche = $LecteurZip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.fullname -match $Cible}

        if ($Recherche.Count -lt 1)
        { Write-Host("Impossible de retirer l'élément < $Cible > de < $Zip > !!") }
        else
        {
            foreach ($e in $Recherche)
            { $e.Delete() }
        }

        $LecteurZip.Dispose()
    }
    else
    { Write-Host("Le Fichier Zip < $Zip > n'est pas valide !!") }
}
```